# Is mongod --repair still a blocking task in MongoDB 1.8?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a 5GB database I want to compact and repair. Unfortunately, I have an active application running on that database.

I'm wondering if running a `mongod --repair` task with MongoDB 1.8 will block all the other write operations on the database.

I don't want to shutdown the entire application for hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `repairDatabase` is a blocking operation, which means you'll need to do it during a scheduled maintenance window.

Alternately, if you are using a replica set, it's possible to repair with no down time by taking one member out of the replica set, repairing it, re-adding it to the replica set, and repeating until all are repaired. See [the note in yellow at the end of this section](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair#DurabilityandRepair-RepairCommand) for more info and caveats.

Comment: I should also note, you can perform a repair with `db.repairDatabase()` in the mongo shell, not only with the `--repair` command-line flag. However, this is still a blocking operation, just a different way of invoking it.

Answer (score 3):

You may take a look at --journal key. It keeps binary log for last operations and recovery may take much less time than repair.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Comment: It's also usable when you don't want to keep extra replica sets and want to have good backup on Amazon AWS. It allows to do EBS snapshots from working mongo without any impact